# How to configure spock framework in Springboot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, pom.xml, spock

I want to use Spock for testing in my spring boot application.
My application is using java, but I want Spock to use groovy for testing.

I have added these 2 dependencies in my pom.xml file.

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Am i missig something.

Comment: Have a look at the https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/ project, you are still missing the gmaven compiler. What version of spock and spring do you want to use?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings Spring boot version 2.3.1.RELEASE and spock version 2.0-M3-groovy-2.5 and gmavenplus-plugin 1.6 as mention in the spock example. I am using intellij Idea and i am not able to run the test. `class HelloSpec extends Specification {
    def "maximum"(){
        expect:
        Math.max(1,2)==2
    }
}`

Comment: Please do not post code in comments, rather update the question. I also suggest you post your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub in order to make the problem reproducible. You seem to be doing this for the first time, so there are many possible root causes for your problem. Analysis trumps speculation, so please show us more than just some Maven and Spock snippets. Thank you. 

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `gmavenplus-plugin` which compiles your groovy sources.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                        <goal>compileTests</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```